# IdentityUserLogin does not contain a definition for User

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

**I was trying to build an asp.net MVC-5 project** when i suddenly had this *error*

> Error 1   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin'
>   does not contain a definition for 'User' and no extension method
>   'User' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\Projects\FULL\Control
>   Panel\ControlPanel.Web\Models\IdentityModels.cs   53  56  ControlPanel.Web

which i do not know the nature of it provided that i have all the necessary packages installed via nugget.

[image: the error I have]

**ALL I WAS TRYING TO DO IS CONFIGURING SOME RELATIONSHIPS!**

[image: some code that doesn't compile in the OnModelCreating override]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I figured it out at last** >>

I was using **Microsot.Aspnet.Identitly assembly** *version 2* where they got rid of the navigation properties that existed in version 1 some how,, couldn't imaging such inconsistency due to a small nuget update.

Comment: Hi, is there a fix? Or you just remove the relationship configuration?